# How do I draw a rectangle in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

How do I make a component to draw one rectangle on the page?

I've already tried this.

EDIT: I pulled the code sample from a React-Native tutorial. I assumed that I could use it in react.js.

EDIT2: I should have been more clear. I am developing a website.

```
class tierbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.rectangle}></View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is about react native... I guess

Comment: Yes, in a css file.

Comment: Are you developing for mobile or web?

Comment: Web, I realize I should have been more clear on this.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you will be drawing this with html element and css.

1. render a `<div className="rectangle" />`
2. load a style in the html somewhere that describes the rectangle

```
.rectangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

Of course there are other ways to draw rectangle depending on your need e.g. [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Comment: Is step 1 in the rectangle.js or app.js?

Comment: It can be anywhere you want @BobbyZhang .
Also this is assuming you're building a browser app, not a react-native and I just realized that you pulled this from react-native, which has `<View />` component built in

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `width` and `height` for it to appear and it's good if it have a background color so you can see it.

```
class Tierbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.rectangle}></View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
    rectangle: {
        width: '50px',
        height: '50px',
    }
}
```